# Tornado: Can I run code after calling self.finish() in an asynchronous RequestHandler?

Tags: python, tornado

I'm using Tornado.  I have a bunch of asynchronous request handlers.  Most of them do their work asynchronously, and then report the result of that work back to the user.  But I have one handler whose job it is to simply tell the user that their request is going to be processed at some point in the future.  I finish the HTTP connection and then do more work.  Here's a trivialized example:

```
class AsyncHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # first just tell the user to go away
        self.write("Your request is being processed.")
        self.finish()

        # now do work
        ...
```

My question is: is this a legitimate use of Tornado?  Will the code after the self.finish() run reliably?  I've never had a problem with it before, but now I'm seeing a problem with it in one of my development environments (not all of them).  There are a number of work-arounds here that I've already identified, but I want to make sure I'm not missing something fundamental to the request-lifecycle in Tornado.  There doesn't SEEM to be a reason why I wouldn't be able to run code after calling self.finish(), but maybe I'm wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem you're seeing? The IOLoop will remain blocked until your function completes, so if the work you're doing is taking any length of time, you'll want to find another way to do it..

Answer (score 31):

**Yes, you can.**

You have to define `on_finish` method of your `RequestHandler`. This is a function run after the request finished and has sent the response to client.

> [`RequestHandler.on_finish()`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.on_finish)
>
> Called after the end of a request.
>
> Override this method to perform cleanup, logging, etc. This method is
>   a counterpart to prepare. on_finish may not produce any output, as it
>   is called after the response has been sent to the client.

Comment: +1 1k views and no upvotes, for such nice and clear answers oO

Answer (score 6):

Yes, your code after `self.finish()` will work reliably. But you can't call `self.finish()` twice - it will raise an exception. You can use `self.finish()` to close connection before all work on server is done.

But as Cole Maclean told - don't do heavy work after finish. 
Look for another way to do heavy tasks in background.

Comment: And of course you cannot write anything after calling self.finish(). Heavy tasks cannot be done in tornado's ioloop in any way, because that will block all other requests. The good way to do a heavy task is to start a new thread or to process heavy tasks in a different process (and use some kind of IPC between tornadoweb and the other process)

Comment: @nagylzs, agree at 100%. There are a lot of solutions for delegating task to another process.