# Can not finish a RequestHandler in Tornado with self.finish()

Tags: tornado

This is my code for Facebook Messenger Platform using Tornado.

```
class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    try:
        mode = self.get_argument("hub.mode")
        token = self.get_argument("hub.verify_token")
        challenge = self.get_argument("hub.challenge")
    except tornado.web.MissingArgumentError:
        self.set_status(400)
        self.write("Bad request")
        self.finish()

    if mode == "subscribe" and token == "secretgarden":
        self.set_status(200)
        self.write(challenge)
        self.finish()
    else:
        self.set_status(403)
        self.write("GTFO")
        self.finish()
```

The problem is when I run it (lack of `hub.mode` arg), it will catch `MissingArgumentError` and throw out:

```
File "index.py", line 20, in get
if mode == "subscribe" and token == "secretgarden":
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mode' referenced before assignment
```

I expect when it catch my `MissingArgumentError` exception, it will return `400` and end my request. But it still running next code. Did I do anything wrong?

P.s: I have tried add `return` after `self.finish()`, it worked, but I have not seen anyone do it. And the docs said:

> RequestHandler.finish(chunk=None) Finishes this response, ending the
>   HTTP request.

And I also read this question: [Tornado: Can I run code after calling self.finish() in an asynchronous RequestHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696291/tornado-can-i-run-code-after-calling-self-finish-in-an-asynchronous-requestha)

Something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `finish` does not return from your method. You have to add a `return` statement, otherwise the next statement in your method is executed.

Actually, you don't need to call `finish` at all: Tornado request handlers automatically call `finish` once a coroutine like `get` completes.

So, to fix your problem, replace your `self.finish()` calls with `return` statements.

[This answer is related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22967996/tornado-what-is-the-difference-between-web-asynchronous-gen-coroutine-vs-gen)

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. And thanks for your tip. :)

Answer (score 2):

Returning at the end of endpoint methods is a good solution, however it won't work if you need to finish (e.g. by redirecting) from other methods like `prepare`, `initialize` and `get_current_user`, as they are not necessarily last in the call stack. The "official" method is to raise the [`tornado.web.Finish`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Finish) exception, which will bubble up and break execution from anywhere in the code. I've been using things like this extensively:

```
class SomeHandler(SomeMoreGenericHandler):

    def prepare(self):
        super().prepare()
        if not self.current_user:
            self.redirect('/login')
            raise tornado.web.Finish
```

Comment: And yes, I know that this is essentially equivalent of using the `@tornado.web.authenticated` decorator, but this is just an example.